# VSCode some shortcuts not working properly

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

latest version 1.40.1 on Windows 7 x64. I am developing in Java.

The most common shortcut, "go to definition"  F12 and "auto fix" ctrl+dot
I tested it on another computer with 1.40.1. It works properly.
I have follow the key binding troubleshooting guide. When I record my key ctrl+dot.
It shows ctrl+oem_period. Looks like the OS is sending the correct keys to VSCode.

I couldn't find a way to reset VSCode key bindings and do not know what is actually causing this.
What should I do next? Completely reinstall everything is the last resort.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your operating system keyboard shortcut is overriding the vscode shortcut. You should check your operating system shortcut key instead.

Comment: VSCode working properly before update. I didn't change anything on my OS. How do I check and allow VSCode to override OS shortcut?

Comment: I think vs code can't override other keys you have to find the software culprit and change that instead

Comment: I use hotkey commander to find F12 is used by System (Ssytem Debugger), but do not know which process it is.

Comment: I have fixed it. By removing duplication key binding. But I don't know which extensions add those binding. F12 and crtl+. is bound to some changing Focus Stuff.

Comment: thanks, I checked and turned out there was another software that runs in a background that using the same shortcut key with VS Code

Comment: Change your "keyboard.dispatch" to keyCode in the file settings.json

{
    "keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode"
}

fixed for me!

Comment: Yes here is my situation. 
My Ctrl+Shift was on change language and ctrl+shift in VSCode dosnt work

Answer (score 72):

With the command `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting`, you can see which command is linked to a shortcut. It could happen that an extension is overriding the expected behaviour.

For example, I had an extension overriding the shortcut to reopen a closed tab, which didn't work anymore.

Comment: Add "Keyboard event cannot be dispatched." will suggest you should look at some other software. The above in combination with https://defkey.com/what-means/ctrl-shift-l helped me track down it was Radeon that had hijacked a shortcut.

Comment: thanks for advice, in my Xfce case i had shortcuts like Ctrl+F4 bound in WindowManager.

Comment: How to run `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting` in Windows?

Comment: @Jeb50 Open Command Palette (`Ctrl+Shift+P`) and search for it.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. As of now, another easy way is `F1`.

Comment: Nice. I just discovered another extension had hijacked cmd + shift + T (reopen closed editor).

Answer (score 15):

This resolves my issue:

Change your "keyboard.dispatch" to keyCode in the file **settings.json**

```
{
    "keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode"
}
```

Comment: I worked for me! The problem was using a secondary keyboard. In the main keyboard worked fine. Now everything is great!

Comment: further info: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_troubleshooting-keybindings

Answer (score 12):

In my case, "cmd+k cmd+0" which helps to fold all regions  was not working.
Another extension was using the same shortcut. I followed the steps below to fix it.

**Here are the steps to fix this**

1. Press "cmd+shift+p" to open command palette
2. Type "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts" and hit enter
3. Press "option+cmd+k" to start recording keys.
4. Press the short cut keys that are not working (in my case "cmd+k cmd+0" ). This will list all the instances of that shortcut keys. And there are probably multiple instances of the same keybindings with some of them being used by an "Extension" as shown under the "Source" column.
5. Remove that and keep only that instance which says "Default" under "Source" column.

Now, you should able to use the default keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 7):

Just restarted the Visual Studio Code and the keys are working fine.

Comment: This worked for me as well.  What was weird was that I added a bunch of keybindings all at once and only a couple of them refused to work until I restarted.  Some of them worked immediately.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem after I updated my Intel Graphics Command Center using Windows Updates.

The <kbd>Add One Cursor Above/Below</kbd> shortcuts were not working for me.

I started the **Intel Graphics Command Center**, and then went to **System > Hotkeys** tab, **Enabled System Hotkeys** as shown in the picture below.

[image]

I flipped my screen a couple of times using the keyboard shortcuts and then **disabled** once again.

Then switched back to VSCode and the keyboard shortcuts were working!!

Answer (score 3):

On VS Code,

1. Click on **Help**, then click on **Show All Commands**.  OR you can open the command palette directly with shortcut: ctrl + shift + p (on Windows/Linux) or cmd + shift + p (on Mac).
2. Paste **Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting** on the search bar.
3. Click on the gear sign next to the command
   [image: Refer the image]
4. You may have keybinding search input there so click on the last icon 'Clear Keybinding Search Input(Escape)'
   [image: click on the highlighted icon]
5. Search the desired keyboard shortcut and see if any result is there. If you find any entry, right click and remove keybinding.

Answer (score 2):

You may also need to check the `when` clause of the Keybinding.  In my case, I was struggling with why "Command+R" wasn't reloading the window on my Mac.  By right-clicking on the row of the relevant command in Keyboard Shortcuts, then clicking "Change When Expression" and removing the expression completely, the keybinding now works as expected.
Source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108393#issuecomment-706215895

Answer (score 1):

Resolved :

Facing similar issue. Several keyboard shortcuts stop working when code starts running.
In my case it was happening because of notepad++ extension. Disabling that extension resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this can happen because of change in environment variables. Please check if any recent program installations has made that change

Answer (score 1):

Try turning on Num Lock, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

99% works.

Forget everything that may overrides your keyboard shortcuts. The problems is your `keybindings.json` file, if you fix it you'll fix your problem.

I found the solution and I've explained it in the following link:
[Why vscode shortcuts don't work properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72160825/why-vscode-shortcuts-dont-work-properly/72187880#72187880)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have installed some "vim keyboard extensions" and others. so I have uninstalled all the extensions related to the "keyboard" i.e. "vim keyboard extension" and now it is working fine. it is recommended to check if you have downloaded any extensions for the "keyboard" in the extensions and uninstall it. It might solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS users,

This is a default macOS shortcut.  VSCode is never getting the meta+shift+L message from your OS.  Your OS is hijacking it.  You need to disable it.

**System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services > uncheck: Search with Google**

---

Source: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000435950/comments/360000170990

This is a default macOS shortcut, you can disable it at System Settings | Keyboard | Shortcuts | Services| Search with Google.
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180038/strange-behavior-within-ms-word-using-command-shift-l-launches-safari-sometimes

Answer (score 1):

Extensions you add to VSCode also can override the ordinary behavior of shortcuts. I faced to this problem, I've noticed that the ordinary shortcut `command` + `L` which selects the whole line, does not work, and the reason was `Live Server` extension, which overrides that shortcut, after its deletion shortcut became work properly

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I can't use ctrl+`. I've tried to restart VS Code but this problem still occurs.

After some checking, I figure out that my keyboard language accidentally changed to Japanese, after switching to English, the shortcut ran perfectly.

[Pict. Change keyboard Language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puvpt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many methods to solve this problem ,not every problem of mine got solved so I use this method after I cant find the solution.
you can first uninstall the VS code and then delete the .vscode file from C=>user=>admin=>.vscode
after that reinstall vscode ,from my end its working fine after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is niche but never know, might help someone - YouTube Music Desktop player app was hijacking `cmd, shift + l` for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my Ctrl keys were mapped to the Toggle extension and this extension could not overwrite one of my settings in the settings.json because I had pending changes that hadn't been saved. Once I saved the file, I was able to use the toggle keyboard binding again. I used the guidance from Martin above to determine the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Woo, found my issue was Razor Naga stuff. After I updated some of the Razor apps (it has Synapse, Cortex, etc), this issue started happening. Now, I saw these apps are running in the background although I am not using the devices at this time, and once I quit them, VSCode went back to normal thankfully.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to fix CTRL+Space "Trigger Suggest". First I found and disabled this setting in: System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Input Sources

[image: keyboard_prefs]

Then I followed @ryandidevar's instructions and replaced everything for Mac: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72187880/14353462

Finally, I set "Trigger Suggest" in VSCode > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts to: CTRL+§ (which is right next to my "Z" key). CTRL+Space just would not be accepted under any circumstance. Now hitting CTRL+§ finally brings up the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted folder in `%APPDATA%\Code\` resets whole vs code and fixed my problem with <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> and other vs code shorcuts not working

Answer (score 0):

For me, It is the keyboard layout setting that causes this. Use English US keyboard setting.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, The installed extensions may be the cause, **For example:**

I installed "Vim" extension Thus, Some shortcuts failed to work again. Some of those shortcuts are: "Ctrl + A" , "Ctrl+C", "Ctrl+X" but I uninstalled VIM extension to make my shortcuts work again!

> Why? Some extensions has their own shortcuts which can confuse you because of different functionalities!

Answer (score 0):

- Go to keyboard shortcuts as follows `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` 
  [image]
- Open keyboard Shortcut (JSON) file
  [image]
- It will show something like this...
  [image]
- Go to this link [check here](https://github.com/codebling/vs-code-default-keybindings/blob/master/windows.keybindings.json) and add that content to that above `keybindings.json` file
- Save them and check your short cut.
  It should work now... It worked for me... All the best...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using command pallete , shortcut option ,
I followed the following steps,

```
View /CommandPallete/keyboard Shortcuts
```

Just take a look that, is there any extension  using those shortcut to invoke their functionality.
In my case BlackBox extension was using those shortcut to launch their tab.

Answer (score 0):

Delete any vs code extension you have downloaded that has its commands.