# Why vscode shortcuts don't work properly?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I've recently updated my VSCode and most of its shortcuts don't work anymore. I tried to reinstall my VSCode but it didn't work. I've checked if it's affected by any other system shortcuts but I wasn't lucky enough and none of them worked for me.
Some shortcuts like:
**ctrl + d,
ctrl + shift + k,
etc.**

Comment: Try downgrading to the previous version if it worked. It's the fastest and the easiest way. Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10.

Comment: I will assume that keyboard bindings have been modified somehow. You can try resetting them from the settings.

Comment: Here is my full solution which makes use of @ryan's: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72993921/14353462

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem.

1. go to : `File>Preferences>Keyboard Shortcut`

[image]

2. Then from upright of the page select the icon that says `open keyboard shortcuts`. Like below

[image]

3. In the `keybindings.json` tab you may see something like this:

[image]

Replace everything with the settings from the following links:

if you are using  `windows` copy settings from this link: [windows.keybindings.json](https://github.com/codebling/vs-code-default-keybindings/blob/master/windows.keybindings.json)

for `mac`: [macos.keybindings.json](https://github.com/codebling/vs-code-default-keybindings/blob/master/macos.keybindings.json)

for `linux`: [linux.keybindings.json](https://github.com/codebling/vs-code-default-keybindings/blob/master/linux.keybindings.json)

and if you want to see `all available options` see this link: [vs-code-default-keybindings](https://github.com/codebling/vs-code-default-keybindings)

4. after saving the file, your vscode shortcuts will work properly again.

Comment: Thank you posting this. No one seems to believe me when I posted this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution worked like a charm. I had added custom shortcuts in VS Code on my Mac, and after a while, I noticed that other shortcuts were not working properly. If anyone using VS Code on a Mac is experiencing issues after adding custom shortcuts, this solution should help.

Comment: This works really well me as well... Thanks a lot...

Comment: This is just overriding the default keybindings. This is not supposed to be a solution, and not supposed to work unless nothing is set in the default keybindings. The links in this answer are "default" keybindings. I think there is some problem with VSCode (or some other setting is not set properly) if this answer works.

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons. First check that if there is any other application overrides the shortcuts or not.

Comment: I've checked it somehow but what is your suggestion? what is the best way to do this? and after finding the specific application what should I do next?

Comment: Check this thread    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58946149/vscode-some-shortcuts-not-working-properly#:~:text=It%20could%20happen%20that%20an,which%20didn't%20work%20anymore.&text=Add%20%22Keyboard%20event%20cannot%20be,look%20at%20some%20other%20software.

Comment: Follow thsese steps  to reset keyboart shortcut binding, https://ourtechroom.com/tech/reset-keyboard-bindings-visual-studio-code/

Comment: There is no option for me such as step 5. So I can't reset anything. ;((

Answer (score 1):

For those still looking for an answer, if you have multiple keyboard languages defined, Windows provides a very annoying `Ctlr+Shift` keyboard binding to switch between them.

I had to disable this as it was interrupting some of keyboard bindings I wanted to use in VS Code.

Here is a [guide](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-delete-shortcut-ctrl-shift/ad520f7a-b08f-42de-a4b5-ec06e7988d6f) on how to do that.

Comment: In my case win10 IME simp/trad switch default to Ctrl-Shift + F

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple VS windows, some binded keys are did not work. In my case, everything worked when I closed the windows. Except a one window.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32234775)